# When mod_rewrite is on cant access css or js

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %[REQUEST_FILENAME] !-d 
RewriteCond %[REQUEST_FILENAME] !-f 
RewriteCond %[REQUEST_FILENAME] !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

If I type in browser:
http://quick-mvc/public/css/style.css

Result: white screen, blank css file, even when I inspect with chrome and click the link its blank

If I turn RewriteEngine off then the css file will appear no problem with the same link.

I have searched for similar problems, I am just really confused. It seems like a complex subject.

So basically, I am building this model view controller project and I cannot get css or js to work with mod_rewrite on.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Done. Still does not load css file.

Comment: also you need to use `{}` brackets ie `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` thats the main problem as your rules are not valid

Comment: dude! I am embarrassed! Geez. Should I delete this entire post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes as a programmer you make silly mistakes and it can throw you into some major frustrations.

As cmorrissey mentioned above, I must use curly braces instead of square. Whoops. Lesson learned. :)

It is all good though and I am now going to be more careful and meticulous in my code troubleshooting. This process was not void of learning.

**Solution**

Curly brackets

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

NOT square!

```
RewriteCond %[REQUEST_FILENAME] !-d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can (must?) set RewriteBase value:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: curly braces instead of square brackets fixed the problem.